# Is $E\ni x\mapsto(x,x)$ only measurable if $E$ is a Polish space?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space and $$f:E\to E\times E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto(x,x).$$ I've read that $f$ is $(\mathcal E,\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E)$-measurable, if $E$ is a Polish space and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$. I don't get why $E$ needs to be a Polish space. If $\pi_i:E\times E\to E$ denotes the projection onto the $i$th coordinate, then $\pi_i\circ f=\text{id}_E$ is obviously $(\mathcal E,\mathcal E)$-measurable. So, $f$ should be $(\mathcal E,\mathcal E\otimes\mathcal E)$-measurable. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you justify the "So,"

Comment: @mathworker21 That's a more general property. $f:E\to F_1\times F_2$ is $(\mathcal E,\mathcal F_1\otimes\mathcal F_2)$ measurable if and only if $\pi_i\circ f$ is $(\mathcal E,\mathcal F_i)$-measurable.

Comment: Are you proposing $E$ can be an arbitrary topological space? You need to be able to talk about $\mathcal{B}(E)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I'm claiming that $E$ doesn't need to be a topological space at all. $f$ should be measurable for any measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 $\mathcal B(E)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ if $E$ is a topological space. Read the question: I've said that I read that the measurability would follow in the special case where $E$ is Polish and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$. I claim that this assumption is not needed, i.e. $(E,\mathcal E)$ can be an arbitary measurable space.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. I think the "direct" argument as to why $f$ is measurable is that $f^{-1}(R_1\times R_2) = R_1\cap R_2$ for any $R_1,R_2 \in \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Okay. I just was confused, since I found the claim as an exercise in a lecture note. Don't know what the author had in mind.

Comment: Yea, I know what you mean. Feel free to look at my answer to another one of your questions :)

Comment: You are confused. As stated, $\mathrm{E}$ need be only a measurable space and $f$ will always be measurable. What is true, however, is that for $f$ to be $(\mathscr{B}(\mathrm{E}), \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{E}^2))$-measurable it is sufficient that $\mathrm{E}$ should be a metrizable separable measurable space.

Comment: Or more generally, a second-countable topological space.

Comment: @WillM. Don't understand your comment. As you wrote, $f$ is measurable in general. However, we know that $\mathcal B(E^2)=\mathcal B(E)\otimes\mathcal B(E)$ if $E$ is Polish. Guess that's what you mean.

Comment: $\mathscr{B}(\mathrm{E}^2) = \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{E}) \otimes \mathscr{B}(\mathrm{E})$ if $\mathrm{E}$ is a second-countable topological space.